# get selected text into a variable VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, selectedtext

Is there an easy way to get selected text into a variable similar to native variable ${lineNumber} which is the current selected line number? It would be very useful as a parameter for link to online help etc. Thank you.

Comment: the easiest way you can get the current selected text I know of is...
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
var selection = editor.selection;
var text = editor.document.getText(selection);

Answer (score 2):

It will be $(selectedText} once [this vscode github code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/39483) is released.

Edit: It's actually available now.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use this variable in VSCode?

Comment: this variable is to be used in debugging and task configurations: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference